# DRF's nested relations: serializer output OrderedDict with Tuple

Tags: python, django

I'm following [this guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) to serialize an object and its nested relations:

```
class EmployeeWorkShift(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(CompanyEmployees, unique=True)
    work_shift = models.ForeignKey(WorkShift, unique=True, related_name='employee_work_shifts')

class WorkShift(models.Model):
    workers = models.ManyToManyField('CompanyEmployees', through='EmployeeWorkShift')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class EmployeeWorkShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkShift
        fields = ('id')

class WorkShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_work_shifts = EmployeeWorkShiftSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = WorkShift
        fields = ('id', 'employee_work_shifts')
    depth = 1
```

However, when I do

```
WorkShiftSerializer(WorkShift.objects.get(pk=1)).data
```

I get:

```
{'employee_work_shifts': [OrderedDict([('id', 13)]), OrderedDict([('id', 14)])], 'id': 1}
```

It seems that DRF treated *employee_work_shifts* as list of OrderedDict...

Did I miss anything obvious?

requirements.txt:

```
djangorestframework==3.1.2
Django==1.7.8
```

Comment: You might benefit from telling us what it is you expected, explicitly.  It will help people understand the question more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem: I ran

```
WorkShiftSerializer(WorkShift.objects.get(pk=1)).data
```

in iPython (by python manage.py shell_plus).

I guess somehow iPython screwed up the object type. When I run it in server (python manage.py runserver), it behaves correctly.